# math.h default rounding mode not clear

Tags: c, math, floating-point, type-conversion, rounding

I am facing very strange fact about rounding of `float` and conversion to `int`.

As is stated here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html

Rounding to nearest representable value is default rounding mode. But it doesn`t seem to be.

So I have created this simple program:

```
#include <fenv.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int a;
double b;

main() {
  b=1.3; a=b; printf("%f %d\n",b,a);
  b=1.8; a=b; printf("%f %d\n",b,a);
  b=-1.3; a=b; printf("%f %d\n",b,a);
  b=-1.8; a=b; printf("%f %d\n",b,a);
  printf("%d %d %d\n",fegetround(),FE_TONEAREST,FE_TOWARDZERO);
}
```

Program was compiled with gcc-4.7 (debian), cygwin gcc and Visual studio. Output was same, only definition of `FE_TOWARDZERO` changed.

Output of program:

```
 1.300000 1
 1.800000 1
-1.300000 -1
-1.800000 -1
0 0 3072
```

So we can clearly see, that rounding mode is set to `FE_TONEAREST` (default) in all tested compilers, but all of them are rounding towards zero.

Why?

PS: Yes, I can use `Math.round()` but I am wondering why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found question why is this happening.
As is stated here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-floating-point-to-integer-conversions

in chapter

```
A Closer Look at Float-to-Int Conversions
```

> The problem with casting from floating-point numbers to 32-bit
>   integers stems from the ANSI C standard, which states the conversion
>   should be effected by truncating the fractional portion of the number
>   and retaining the integer result. Because of this, whenever the
>   Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 compiler encounters an (int) or a (long)
>   cast, it inserts a call to the _ftol C run-time function. This
>   function modifies the floating-point rounding mode to 'truncate',
>   performs the conversion, and then resets the rounding mode to its
>   original state prior to the cast.

Answer (score 2):

Because the rounding mode applies to floating-point rounding functions. Conversion to `int` always truncates.

Comment: I don`t get it. I can use Math.round(), ceil() or floor() when I want to round floating point. Or do I see it wrong?

Comment: @Mihalko You don't get the fact that `int a = (int)aFloat;` and `int a = round(aFloat);` are not the same.

Comment: but rounding mode in FP coprocessor is used when casting float to int. Anyways, I`ve found the answer here: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-floating-point-to-integer-conversions in chapter "A Closer Look at Float-to-Int Conversions"

Comment: @Mihalko No, it isn't, or at least that's not this rounding mode. Casting to int always truncates, no matter what.

Comment: Yes, it truncates. It is defined in ANSI C standard. But it is done using rounding instruction while rouning mode is set to FE_TOWARDZERO

Comment: @Mihalko ***THE ROUNDING MODE SET IN THE C STANDARD LIBRARY DOESN'T AFFECT THE CPU.*** How should I write it so that you understand? It only affects the functions in the C standard library.

Comment: It affects FPU. Have you seen source? It is configuring fpu in all implementations I have seen. For example: http://cristi.indefero.net/p/uClibc-cristi/source/tree/30cb4b5cd2e3e6da7603d34b5d0c4dd21ed26bff/libm/i386/fesetround.c

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30967/discussion-between-mihalko-and-h2co3)